# Target .net 4.7 without installing the targeting pack

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, msbuild

We have a build server I don't control. The server has Visual Studio 2015 installed.

I would like to compile a project targeting .Net 4.7, but can't install the corresponding targeting pack.

The project is a normal solution with a mix of C# and F# projects. Except for the missing targeting pack it should compile successfully with VS 2015.

Is it possible to copy the required files into the repository and somehow tell msbuild where to look?

Comment: Does Martin`s answer resolve your question? That answer is works for me after test. Besides, If your project target is .Net 4.7, you do not need to tell msbuild where to look the .net folder after copy the .NETFramework\v4.7 folder to the default directory. If .net folder is not the default path, you can use the parameter "FrameworkPathOverride" to override it. If the answer not resolve your question, please let us to know the latest status for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the reference assemblies (in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7`) to a directory and add `/p:FrameworkPathOverride=Path\To\The\Dir` to the invocation of MSBuild.